# CSS Dropdown not working on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a pure CSS menu on hover. Everything works except that when hide the menu and try to show it on hover...it doesnt happen.

Here is my HTML:

```
         <ul id="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="first" id="p-menu">A</a></li>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="last">H</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And My CSS:

```
  #nav-menu {
   position: relative;
     }

       #header .submenu {
        width: 158px;
            height: 133px;
background: url(../images/submenu-bg.png) no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 49px; left: -11px;
display: none;
```

}

```
            #header .submenu li a {
display: block;
margin: 10px 66px 5px 20px;
border: 0 none;
```

}

```
        #header .submenu li a:hover {
display: block;
margin: 10px 66px 3px 20px;
border: 0 none;
```

}

```
           #nav-menu #p-menu:hover ul.submenu {
display: block!important;
```

}

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971833/drop-down-navi-is-not-working-ie-7

Comment: check to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/Zhv67/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub menu `ul` should be nested within your `li`, not after it. Otherwise this is invalid HTML. Also you should put your `p-menu` `id` on the `li` instead of the `a`.

Change:

```
<li><a href="#" class="first" id="p-menu">A</a></li>
<ul class="submenu">
   <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

To:

```
<li id="p-menu"><a href="#" class="first">A</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

[**-- SEE EXAMPLE --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/JEmuU/1/)

Comment: @sandeep Sorry I don't understand?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't saw you put id="p-menu" in LI

Answer (score 1):

Write like this:

```
<li id="p-menu">
 <a href="#" class="first">A</a>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` submenu is outside the `<li>` tag